# local system wide modulepath for Java11 services

Tags: java, maven, java-11

I've defined an API like

```
package eu.ngong.api;

...
import java.util.ServiceLoader;


public interface API {

    // some specified service operation signatures 
    ...
    
    static List<API> getInstances() {
        ServiceLoader<API> services = ServiceLoader.load(API.class);
        List<API> list = new ArrayList<>();
        services.iterator().forEachRemaining(list::add);
        return list;
    }
```

Now I defined and tested a provider module implementing this API with a *module-info.java* like

```
module eu.ngong.mdl {
...
    requires eu.ngong.api;
    provides eu.ngong.api.API with eu.ngong.mdl.Mdl;
}
```

And tested and installed it in local repository on my machine.

Now I did a new maven project for an executable jar that I like to distribute to my colleagues, but without the service implementation (they do their own).
It exposes a *module-info.java* like

```
module eu.ngong.UI {
    requires eu.ngong.api;
    ...
}
```

and I am going to test it using *mvn test*.
Without anything, it will lead to

```
ERROR eu.ngong.UI.UITest - run tests failed: no API module found
```

Sure, because that service module to satisfy the API is not on the modulepath  - namely *eu.ngong.mdl.Mdl*.

**What would be the best way to get the service provider module on the modulepath - to be active at *mvn test* time?**

Best solution for me would be to put something in the local maven configuration file *.m2/repository/settings* - but I could not identify how.

Or I can put some option on the *mvn test* command line - this is also the first time I am trying to do that and would need a hint.

Comment: What do you mean by Java module? Java service? What would you like to put in settings? Please elaborate more in detail what you are trying to do and what you have done so far... code example, pom example etc. would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean with api provider?

Comment: ok - thank you - elaborated a bit - hope my question becomes more clear now

Comment: Wouldn't adding the appropriate module as a test dependency be sufficient (to be honest, I haven't used the Java Module System in any serious form, so I'm not sure if that is sufficient).

Comment: Thought that should work, Mark - however it does not. Mayby mvn puts only dependencies on the modulepath that are actually required. Got to investigate it.

Comment: As a side note, since Java 9, you can do `return ServiceLoader.load(API.class).stream() .map(ServiceLoader.Provider::get) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: thank you for that note, Holger - super!
@Mark: I ran it with *mvn test -X* and can see (if I am right) that the dependency with the service-provider is put on the classpath and missing on the *test modulepath*. That way the service can not be found. Hmm - what to do?

Comment: I've never had such a problem and I've done a whole project using the JPMS (and Maven and JUnit Jupiter). I'm sure that there is something wrong with your setup and I don't think anyone can help you unless you provide a [minimal, complete and reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)